# "Just before he died, (Gregor) Mendel requested that an extensive autopsy be done." Why? Was he simply "very enthusiastic for all kinds of research"?

Tags: medicine, genetics, mendel

NPR's December 30, 2022 article [Why scientists dug up the father of genetics, Gregor Mendel, and analyzed his DNA](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2022/12/30/1142202365/gregor-mendel-genetics-dna-analyzed) includes speculation by those involved about whether Mendel would want his body to be exhumed and his DNA analyzed (if it could be explained to him what DNA was):

> ([Daniel Fairbanks](https://www.uvu.edu/directory/employee/?id=Z3dwZk11dlFrOWRHRHdxSnNmMTBJdz09), a plant geneticist and author of a book called Gregor Mendel: His Life and Legacy) has thought about how Mendel would feel about being disturbed in his grave to satisfy the curiosity of today's scientists.
>
> "I tend to think, from what I know about him, that he very well may have been happy about this," says Fairbanks. "But of course we can't directly ask him."
>
> ([Šárka Pospíšilová](https://www.muni.cz/en/people/38791-sarka-pospisilova), a geneticist who is also the vice rector for research at Masaryk University in Brno) leans toward that theory, too.
>
> "We believe that he would be happy. **We know he was very enthusiastic for all kinds of research," she says – noting that just before he died, Mendel requested that an extensive autopsy be done.**
>
> "He wasn't against research on his own body," she says.
>
> **Even though Mendel knew nothing about DNA or the role that it played in the inheritance patterns he so closely observed, she says, in all likelihood "he wouldn't mind being part of research, even after his death."

**Question:** Why exactly did Mendel request an extensive autopsy be done after his death? Was it simply because "he was very enthusiastic for all kinds of research" in general, or were there some questions he wanted answered even after his death?

Comment: What evidence is there that he requested an extensive autopsy, other than the quote from the article?

Comment: @Curiouser what evidence is there that this isn't sufficient evidence to ask a Stack Exchange question about it? Are you proposing Prof. Pospíšilová made it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first comprehensive biography of Gregor Mendel was Hugo Iltis, *Gregor Johann Mendel: Leben, Werk und Wirkung*, Berlin: J. Springer 1924. On p. [195](https://books.google.com/books?id=AD0MAAAAMAAJ&ots=UyLpfOkVGW&dq=hugo%20iltis&lr&pg=PA195#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Aus Furcht vor dem Scheintod und um die Diagnose seiner Krankheit ganz sicher zu stellen, verlangte er ausdrücklich die Sektion und hatte insgeheim kurz vor seinem Tod einen Klosterfunktionär durch Eidschwur zur Durchführung seines Wunsches verpflichtet. ...
> Bei der Sektion, die von Krankenhausdirektor Dr. Brenner geleitet wurde, war auch der Neffe, Dr. Alois Schindler, damals Mediziner, anwesend. Man konstantierte außer den früher genannten Symptomen chronische Nierenentzündung (Morbus Brightii) als eigentliche Krankheit, die durch Herzhypertrophie kompliziert war.

My translation: "Due to fear of apparent death and to confirm diagnosis of his illness with certainty, he expressly requested autopsy and shortly before his death had secretly pledged a monastery official by oath to carry out his wish. [...] During the autopsy, which was led by hospital director Dr. Brenner, [Mendel's] nephew Dr. Alois Schindler, then a physician, was also present. Besides the previously mentioned symptoms, chronic inflammation of the kidneys (Bright's disease) was identified as the actual underlying illness, complicated by hypertrophy of the heart."